# What kind of JOIN should I use to join these tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following three tables that I am trying to join together and create an overview of all desktops and whoever has one assigned to their UserID if any.

```
dbo.Users
ID    Name     Lastname   JobTitle
118   Ryan     Doe        Field Engineer
119   Jessica  Braun      Technical Consultant
120   Daniel   Sous       Web developer
121   Amy      Amyson     Intern
.. etc

dbo.LightDesktops
ID    Model     MACAddress          UserID
1     HP1234    AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA   118
2     HP1234    BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB   121
3     HP1234    AA:BB:BB:AA:BB:AA   NULL
4     HP1234    BB:AA:BB:AA:AA:BB   124

dbo.MediumDesktops
ID   Model      MACAddress          UserID
1    HP12PRO    AA:AB:AA:BB:AA:BA   132
2    HP12PRO    BB:BA:AB:BA:BB:AA   119
3    HP12PRO    AA:BA:BA:AB:AA:BA   123
4    HP12PRO    BB:BB:BB:AB:BA:BB   241
```

I managed to figure out how to do it per type of desktop, for example LightDesktops:

```
SELECT * FROM LightDesktops LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON LightDesktops.UserID = Users.UserID
```

That will show me a nice overview of the light desktops with their information as well as whoever has one assigned to if any.

If I'd like to have an overview of the light desktops that are not used and therefore in stock I can do

```
SELECT * FROM LightDesktops LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON LightDesktops.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE LightDesktops.UserID IS NULL
```

How can I accomplish the same results, but for both tables containing information of our desktops? I tried to use an UNION but returned me lots of duplicate values.

Comment: Slightly off-topic; have you considered merging light and medium desktops into one table?  You could add an additional column for identifying which are light/medium.  The benefit of this approach is it will simplify the queries you need to write.

Comment: Could you add an example of which columns you wish to see in the output?

Comment: Taking @destination-data's advice might be sound, but also you might not have access to make this change. Alternatively you could use `CREATE VIEW` to get a the join logic in one place, then use the view in all your subsequent queries, at a later stage you may be able to refactor to remove the view.

Comment: Appreciate the advice and you have good a point. It would be much simpler, but I would have to dig back into multiple scripts and whatnot to modify them accordingly. Was wondering if it would be possible without resorting to that first! @destination-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UNION` to bring the light and medium desktops tables together as a single dataset shouldn't give you duplicates unless the tables contain duplicate values in rows accross **all columns** in your `SELECT` clauses and you use `UNION ALL`. *If you know your tables have unique values use `UNION ALL` to give a performance boost.*

I would combine the two tables in a common table expression (cte) and then join the resultant table with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your user table which can also be filtered to find entries where there is no match `WHERE [user].[UserID] IS NULL`, NB, that would return orphaned rows in your desktops tables where the user has been deleted; alternatively drop the left outer join and use `WHERE [desktop].[UserID] IS NULL` to return only dekstops without assiged users.

You could try the following code;

```
WITH cte_Desktop AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID] as [DesktopID],
        'Light Desktop' as [DekstopType],
        [Model],
        [MACAddress],
        [UserID]
    FROM [dbo].[LightDesktops]

    UNION

    SELECT
        [ID],
        'Medium Desktop',
        [Model],
        [MACAddress],
        [UserID]
    FROM [dbo].[MediumDesktops]
)

SELECT
    [desktop].*

FROM cte_Desktop AS [desktop]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [user]
    on [user].[UserID] = [desktop].[UserID]

WHERE [user].[UserID] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WITH all as (
select model , userid from LightDesktops
union
select model , userid from MediumDesktops
)

select * FROM all where UserId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Full join` to get report of all users present. it will give you the full report. On top of this results Query for the userid is NULL

```
  SELECT U.ID userid,
       U.NAME,
       LD.USERID LD_USERID,
       LD.MODEL LIGHT_MODEL,
       LD.MACADDRESS LIGHT_MAC,
       LM.USERID LM_USERID,
      LM.MODEL MEDIUM_MODEL,
      LM.MACADDRESS MEDIUM_MAC
FROM   #USERS U
      FULL OUTER JOIN #LIGHTD LD
         ON (U.ID = LD.USERID )
      FULL OUTER JOIN #LIGHTM LM
         ON (LM.USERID = U.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can achieve what you need in a single query, it may be more supportable to break the table union out into a view which allows that logic to be reused across multiple queries and also allows for easier refactoring at a later date.

Nod to [destination-data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572928/destination-data) for reminding me of this.

**View**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Desktops] AS
(
    SELECT
        [ID] as [DesktopID],
        'Light Desktop' as [DekstopType],
        [Model],
        [MACAddress],
        [UserID]
    FROM [dbo].[LightDesktops]

    UNION

    SELECT
        [ID],
        'Medium Desktop',
        [Model],
        [MACAddress],
        [UserID]
    FROM [dbo].[MediumDesktops]
)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    [desktop].*

FROM [dbo].[Desktops] AS [desktop]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [user]
    on [user].[UserID] = [desktop].[UserID]

WHERE [user].[UserID] IS NULL
```